# Unable to fix dependency problems

Tags: updates, dependencies

I've been having a few problems with my Ubuntu now that I've been unable to fix for a few months. Whenever I try to update/install anything new it won't install, including Chrome Updates, running the software updater and various other things.

I've been advised here that I "seem to have dependency problems, most likely due to an interrupted previous installation. Try running sudo apt install -f first to fix any dependency problem", and this has also been the advice given to me by the software updater, which said, "It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the package manager "Synaptic" or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a terminal to fix this issue at first."  However, when I do this in the terminal I keep on getting the following message in response:

```
  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libde265-0 libfwup1 libheif1 libllvm6.0 libllvm7 libllvm8
  linux-modules-4.15.0-1043-oem linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1036
  linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1038 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1039
  linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1043 oem-fix-tlp-realtek-lp1819812-blacklistr8153
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 237 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 16.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 336469 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem (4.15.0-1043.48) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-1043-oem
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem (4.15.0-1050.57) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-1050-oem
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-1043-oem
 linux-image-4.15.0-1050-oem
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I can never progress past this stage. Is anyone able to offer any advice? Many thanks, in advance. :-)

Comment: Whilst we weren't able to fix the problem in the end, just wanted to thank everyone for their input, much appreciated and very kind.  We spent a few hours trying to fix it, but we weren't successful, so we went with an alternative instead as it was taking too much working time from us.  Just one of those things,  thanks again for the help!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

For a long shot.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

make sur the 1. line begins with #

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
```

then `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: +1 I don't think this is a long shot at all. It's what the apt output is specifically pointing to as the proximate source of the problem, so it's the *first* thing I would check. Some additional detective work might be needed, or not.

Comment: No one knows how much the file is altered.

Comment: Complete agreement.

Answer (score 0):

After trying

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

`sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status` (you can use vim or gedit instead of nano)
Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

Unlock the dpkg – (message /var/lib/dpkg/lock)

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

All the best !!!

[Reference](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/)

Comment: This seems like the case for dpkg's `--force-remove-reinstreq`, which would seems to accomplish the same with fewer steps. After either method, all the newly-forgotten files must still be cleaned up.